# Why Sensor Simulator Accelerometer Doesn't run with AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, android-sensors, open-intents

First of all I'm trying to use "Openintents Sensor Simulator" program for Android. I installed Sensor Simulator for desktop. After that i installed SensorSimulatorSettings-x.x.x.apk on my Android emulator. At the settings page in android emulator, i use 10.0.2.2 and my local-ip address and socket no 8010.

When i tried to run my program on android device and tried to control the sensors at desktop application, it doesn't change at all. "Orientation","Gravity" and "Accelerometer" parameters changed when i tried to rotate the virtual telehone in desktop program. But program in the android emulator doesn't use these parameters.

P.S: Program works correctly at real android device. Only doesn't work at virtual android emulator.

For example: When rotate from x axis, program prints "You turned right" or rotate from y axis, program prints "You turned up".

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this alternative approach: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into issues with the OpenIntents Sensor Simulator.  Seems that the project hasn't been touched for 3 years, and since their last development effort, Android changed how you are allowed to access the Network.  As a result, any work with the library results in NetworkOnMainThread errors.